# Validation errors only show when out of web middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I have a fresh Laravel install, version 5.2.41, and I want to output validation errors to my template.  Pretty basic stuff.

In my `app.blade.php`:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            {{ $error }}<br>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

My `routes.php` file:

```
Route::group(['as' => 'backend', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'namespace' => 'Backend', 'prefix' => config('settings.admin.slug')], function () {    
    Route::get('/admin_users/edit/{id}', ['uses' => 'AdminUserController@edit', 'as' => 'admin.users.edit']);
    Route::post('/admin_users/edit/{id}', 'AdminUserController@update');
});
```

As you can see I'm using the `web` middleware here.

When in this configuration the `$errors` variable *is* set when it should be, but it is just an empty array.

If I remove the `web` middleware then everything works as it should do.  This seems very strange to me and not expected behaviour.  The obvious fix is to just not include the `web` middleware, but I don't know what side effects that might have.

Comment: maybe you need paste the code of web middleware, so we can see what web middleware did.

Comment: It's the built-in web middleware, so there's no code.  It's simply the classes as defined in the Kernel.php that ships with Laravel: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: By default, all routes are covered by the 'web' middleware. Adding it again seems to break your errors. Ran into this the other night. Run php artisan route:list using CLI from your project directory to see your routes and the middleware they are behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends of the version of Laravel application you use (don't confuse it with Laravel framework).

Look at `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file to verify whether you there `web` middleware applied like in this default file https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

If you do, you shouldn't use this in your `routes.php` files because you duplicate `web` middleware now and it will cause such issues.

So you can either alter your all routes or just remove this `web` middleware from `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`file

Comment: I was aware I definitely wanted the web middleware, so knowing it's always there as default and I was duplicating it is the reassurance I needed. Thanks. Very informative answer